# Rewriting javascript regex in php when regex have escapes

Tags: javascript, php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to write my regex as string (it's part of my S-Expression tokenizer that first split on string, regular expressions and lisp comments and then tokenize stuff between), it works in https://regex101.com/r/nH4kN6/1/ but have problem to write it as string for php.

My JavaScript regex look like this:

```
var pre_parse_re = /("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"])*"|\/(?! )[^\/\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^\/\\]*)*\/[gimy]*(?=\s|\(|\)|$)|;.*)/g;
```

I've tried to write this regex in php (the one from Regex101 was inside single quote).

```
$pre_parse_re = "%(\"(?:\\[\\S\\s]|[^\"])*\"|/(?! )[^/\\]*(?:\\[\\S\\s][^/\\]*)*/[gimy]*(?=\\s|\\(|\\)|$)|;.*)%";
```

My input

```
'(";()" /;;;/g baz); (baz quux)'
```

when called:

```
$parts = preg_split($pre_parse_re, $str, -1,
                    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

it should create same array as in Regex101 (3 matches and stuff between) but it keep splitting on first semicolon inside regex `/;;;/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your escaping might be incorrect. Try this regex instead:

```
$pre_parse_re = "%(\"(?:\\\\[\\\\S\\\\s]|[^\"])*\"|\/(?! )[^\/\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\S\s][^\/\\\\]*)*\/[gimy]*(?=\s|\(|\)|$)|;.*)%";
```

Using `preg_split` might also return more than the capturing groups that you want, so you could also change to use this if you just want the 3 matches.

```
$parts;
preg_match_all($pre_parse_re, $str, $parts, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Your last edit is not needed because I want `3 matches and stuff between` that's why I've used `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`